# Get error with ajax get in jquery to an extern url

Tags: jquery, ajax, get

I have a big problem. I want to get information with a webservice in one url.

But I'm getting this error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load ht*p://external_url_that_i_trid_to_get. 
Origin ht*p://localhost:8888 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

Im using this:

```
$.get(
    url_parsed,
    date_get,
    function(data) {
        if(data.result == 'sucess') {
            alert(data.data["title"]);
        }
    },"json"
);
```

How I can resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i solve the problem using my server as proxy.

With jquery and ajax i call one php script in my server.

This php script does an file_get_contents to the url that i want get json information and do an echo.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

To send a cross-domain AJAX request you need to use `JSONP`.

Comment: i tried but i cant yet..anyone can give me an example off what i have to do?

Answer (score 0):

You are sending a cross domain request. It is not allowed only if the policy allows it.
use a code like this:

```
$.getJSON("link",function(data){
     }
});
```

**Also read this article first:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#JSONP**